# How to make stretchable view with min height inside ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Want I want to achieve is to compose two views, where one has some fixed aspect ratio and the other one stays below the first (unless the first gives enough space for the second one).

Here is one case:

[image: First case]

Here is second case:

[image: Second one]

These two views are placed inside `ConstraintLayout`. I tried to use this part of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="0.75"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_min="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view1"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But it works only in the first case where there is enough space for View 2. In the second case, View 2 is moved below View 1 and it's outside the screen.

**Edit**

I've found solution, which I'm not proud of it, but it works. Still waiting for better idea. How it works? I put additional view (placeholder) which doesn't have constrained width to `MATCH_PARENT` but it has bottom margin (simulating minimum height for View 2). Placeholder behaves in the same way like View 1 when there is more space than minimum height, but in other cases it narrows a little bit to leave bottom margin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="0.75"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/placeholder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="0.75"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/placeholder"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, I don't see you trying to add any constraint to the dimensions of the first view. If you want it to have a fixed aspect ratio of 3:4 you should set `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,3:4"` to your desired view and remove the `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="0.75".` Therefore you won't need the placeholder view any longer. So your layout would look something like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,3:4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view1" />
```

But if you wish to keep your view1 heigh to a 75% screen ratio, then you should replace your placeholder view with a horizontal Guideline to which you set your `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75"`. So the layout would look like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view1" />
```

Also please keep in mind that using `match_parent` inside a `ConstraintLayout` is not recommended. Instead, use the 0dp height/width dimension and set the appropriate constraint for the margins depending on the case (top, bottom / start, end)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working as I was expecting. Keep in mind that when view1 bottom is below line with 100dp height from bottom, view2 is also hidden.