# Constraint Layout with two chained TextViews doesn't render properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to create an layout which renders two `TextViews` packed together as in `picture #1`. Now, when first (red) `TextView` has more text than the allowed space it expands itself to fit it's constraints - which is an expected behaviour, see `picture #2`.

Now when i reverse the situation - make the second (violet) `TextView` expand I'm not getting similar result - `picture #3`. As we can see the second `TextView` doesn't respect the first `TextView` constraints.

The other thing that I've also found is that if we replace the order of `TextViews` in our `*.xml` file as "TextView red -> TextView violet" to "TextView violet <- TextView red" while keeping the constraints it works properly - `picture 4` (but the previous case ie fails again).

[image]

I've used the latest constraint layout libraries:

```
//    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0-alpha2'
```

And the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:background="#f00"
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:text="a"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/b"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        />


    <TextView
        android:background="#f0f"
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:text="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/a"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"/
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you do have an idea how to make two TextViews behave as in picture #1, #2 and #4 i would be very grateful.

Comment: I think this is just a limitation of `ConstraintLayout`. When you have two views that are larger than the container, one of them is going to have to be obscured by the other. It seems that ConstraintLayout gives priority to whichever view is defined last. Perhaps you could use `app:layout_constraintHeight_max` to work around this?

Comment: Yea, I'll probably have to use min height for my case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a minimum height constraint `app:layout_constraintHeight_min="wrap"` to both `TextView`s in order to make sure that both will at least wrap their content, in other words this will make any of the `TextView`s not to be greedy on one another.

Also this will keep both `TextViews` [stretchable while maintaining the minimum height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54323946/how-to-make-stretchable-view-with-min-height-inside-constraintlayout).

The only downside of this that both `TextView`s don't obey to the height constraints, you can see in below pic dashed line of height limits, also the top `TextView` text is cut. This is because both `TextViews` tends to wrap their content while keeping constraints at the same time.

[image]

In my trial, the padding is proportional to the size of the `TextView` and how big is the content of both of them.

A possible workaround to add padding at the top of top `TextView`, and at the Bottom of bottom `Textivew`

Another way to work on is to be strict to height constraint, and don't wrap height content by removing `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"` from both.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#f00"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:text="a"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#f0f"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:text="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/a" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This might lead to a clue to someone's for better solution

Comment: To your second solution. I was already trying out this with `android:gravity="bottom"` for top TextView to get something that behaves to more what I wanted. The first solution with adding paddings/margins is a bit hacky even for me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: misunderstood wanted behavior.
You have 2 options, use

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_min="minimumHeight"
```

or

app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="percentage/100"

Comment: Not the behaviour i want to achieve. When the text is small it should be stacked together.

Comment: You can use then app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="percentage/100" to make textview take portion of the screen

Comment: It's true that setting minimum height would work, but this is just a workaround. I'll probably use it as a last resort.